# Pulling labels from a list of lists

Tags: r

I have a list of lists from which I'd like to pull the labels (I guess they are labels?).

`` list(c(`6` = 2.94200028801843), c(`3` = 2.41666666666667), c(`4` = 2.41867469879518), 
    c(`3` = 2.08779761904762), c(`3` = 2.28125), c(`3` = 2.8125), 
    c(`5` = 2.65124378109453), c(`2` = 2.8125), c(`5` = 2.68550995024876), 
    c(`6` = 2.78467261904762), c(`3` = 1.375), c(`3` = 1.49305555555556), 
    c(`6` = 2.96577380952381), c(`5` = 2.01559196617336), c(`3` = 2.17460317460317), 
    c(`6` = 2.57936507936508), c(`1` = 2.125), c(`3` = 1.3125), 
    c(`3` = 2.30416666666667), c(`7` = 2.36741071428571), c(`3` = 1.06736111111111), 
    c(`7` = 2.42857142857143), c(`2` = 1.375), c(`6` = 1.65922619047619), 
    c(`5` = 1.01026119402985), c(`1` = 2.5), c(`5` = 2.90625), 
    c(`3` = 2.5625), c(`3` = 3.20833333333333), c(`3` = 1.38541666666667), 
    c(`2` = 0.625), c(`4` = 2.43125), c(`1` = 3.375), c(`7` = 2.58705357142857), 
    c(`7` = 2.31919642857143), c(`6` = 2.65401785714286), c(`5` = 1.1875), 
    c(`4` = 2.51428571428571)) ``

I would like the pull the 6,3,4,3, etc. into a vector that I could add to a data frame. I already used tail() to get it into this form - taking the last entry of each list only... now I need to know the number (6,3,4,3) that was the last entry. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `unlist` and get the `names`. If the list is called `l` you can do :

```
vec <- names(unlist(l))
vec
#[1] "6" "3" "4" "3" "3" "3" "5" "2" "5" "6" ....
```

These are characters. If you want to perform some calculation on it you can convert it to integer/numeric using `as.integer`/`as.numeric`.